# Unique List outputted to a new sheet based on 2 drop down criteria and updated on a cell change

Tags: excel, vba, list

firstly sorry for the long question that follows. I have a tricky one here that I am hoping someone can solve.  I have a workbook that has a large list of data from one of my suppliers that I am trying to automate for reporting purposes. Sheet 2 (Written Reports) Column D has a list of supplier numbers, Column E has the Brand, Column K has the category, and Column N has the product description.
Sheet 1 (Supplier Overview Report) Has a drop down in Cells B1 for supplier name to get the supplier number in C1, B2 has a dropdown for category which outputs into C2.

I have been lucky enough on here to get some help and get a VBA code that allows me to type in manually a supplier number into C1 and a unique list is generated onto Sheet 1 Cell A18 onwards but what I am hoping to achieve is furthering this code to activate the cell change function to be based on using the B1 dropdown. Then add additional code to further refine the unique list based on the C2 value from the dropdown in there which will be dependent on Sheet 1 column K.

Example is I select supplier A from Sheet 2, B1. The vlookup returns supplier #1. This generates a unique list in Sheet1 A18 of all supplier #1 products.  Then I select Fish from B2 dropdown which returns value FSH in C2. Sheet1 A18 then regenerates Sheet1 A18 to show only Supplier #1 FSH category products.

Below is the code I have for the manual typing in of supplier number only which works a treat, but need to expand this further to allow for people in the company who are not computer literate to use.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Address = "$E$1" And Len(.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then
            Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
            Dim i As Long, sKey As String, sSupp As String
            Dim lastRow As Long, arrData
            Dim oSht1 As Worksheet
            Set oSht1 = Sheets("Written Reports")
            sSupp = .Value
            lastRow = oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngData = oSht1.Range("D1:N" & lastRow)
            arrData = rngData.Value
            Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
                sKey = arrData(i, 1) ' Col D [Supplier]
                If StrComp(sSupp, sKey, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    objDic(arrData(i, 11)) = ""
                End If
            Next i
            ' Write Product list to sheet
            lastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If lastRow > 16 Then Me.Range("A17:A" & lastRow).ClearContents
            If objDic.Count > 0 Then Me.Range("A17").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Attached is a sample of where the data that I will be using is layed out in a workbook.

Thanks heaps for any assistance

[image]

[image: Written Reports Page]

| Supplier | B | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | A | 1 |  |  |  | Fish | FSH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category | Poultry | CHK |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | B | 2 |  |  |  | Beef | BF |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | C | 3 |  |  |  | Lamb | SHP |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | D | 4 |  |  |  | Poultry | CHK |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | E | 5 |  |  |  | Fruit | FRT |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Vegetable | VEG |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Product |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

|  |  |  | Vendor |  | Brand |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 1 |  | AAA |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Apple |
|  |  |  | 2 |  | ABC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Carrot |
|  |  |  | 3 |  | DEF |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Apricot |
|  |  |  | 4 |  | GHI |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Fish |
|  |  |  | 4 |  | GHI |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Steak |
|  |  |  | 1 |  | AAA |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Pear |
|  |  |  | 2 |  | ABC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Peas |
|  |  |  | 1 |  | AAA |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Banana |
|  |  |  | 3 |  | DEF |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Zucchini |

Comment: `to get the supplier number in E1` Is it `E1` or `C1`?

Comment: Thanks taller, you saved my bacon on the last one. It will be C1, on the code above you created the cells werent merged.  C1 is where the vlookup will populate and that is the number I wish to use.

Comment: Please edit your post to update it ( `E1` and `E2` ) .

Comment: And 
[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). It's helpful for code testing.

Comment: I am happy to upload the sample workbook when I find where to do it.

Comment: A workbook with vba code is risky. I don't think SO users want to download it. MD table is a nice way to share sample data.

Comment: The Sample book doesnt have the code in it, just the layout. I will try to work out MD table, can get it to generate the sheet, just need to get it to here.

Comment: `Category` Col is missing in the 2nd table.

Answer (score 0):

- The supplier or category filtering criteria might be blank, so add code to handle it.
- ***Note:*** the snippet should be stored in `Supplier Overview Report` sheet module

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
        Dim i As Long, sKey As String
        Dim lastRow As Long, arrData, oSht1 As Worksheet
        Dim sSupp As String, sCate As String
        Dim bSupp As Boolean, bCate As Boolean
        Const KEY_COL = 3 ' Col C (vlookup)
        Const S_ROW = 18 ' start row# of output
        sSupp = Me.Cells(1, KEY_COL).Value
        sCate = Me.Cells(2, KEY_COL).Value
        Set oSht1 = Sheets("Written Reports")
        lastRow = oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngData = oSht1.Range("D2:N" & lastRow)
        arrData = rngData.Value
        Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            ' Col D [Supplier]
            If Len(sSupp) Then
                bSupp = (StrComp(sSupp, arrData(i, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0)
            Else ' no supplier filtering
                bSupp = True
            End If
            ' Col K [Category]
            If Len(sCate) Then
                bCate = (StrComp(sCate, arrData(i, 8), vbTextCompare) = 0)
            Else ' no category filtering
                bCate = True
            End If
            If bSupp And bCate Then
                objDic(arrData(i, 11)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
        ' Write Product list to sheet
        lastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If lastRow >= S_ROW Then Me.Range("A" & S_ROW & ":A" & lastRow).ClearContents
        If objDic.Count > 0 Then Me.Range("A" & S_ROW).Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Posted code on page, C1 and C2 both have vlookup formulas to handle data, when either dropdown is changed it clears any data in A18 onwards but not populating.  Sorry

Comment: pls share sample data.

Comment: Feeling really silly here but cannot figure out how to share sample :(  Sorry

Comment: Paste excel data to makedown web site, copy MD table. Edit your post to paste MD table.

Comment: I've tested the code w/o issues. Please check the gif on my answer.